# How to use shader for drawing FBO lwjgl

Tags: shader, lwjgl, mask, fragment-shader

I am making a 2D game and I want to make a light mask. So far i made a Frame Buffer where i hold my mask but I cannot apply the shader on it. When I don't use the shader the light map is drawn properly (without the scene so for this code i drawns a black screen with one white rectangle) but when i try to blend it with the scene it just draws black screen. This is how i draw the frame buffer and apply the shader.

```
//draw scene

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, m_frameBufferObject);//enable frame buffer
            glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
            glViewport(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  

            //fill with black
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2f(0, 0);
                glVertex2f(1920, 0);
                glVertex2f(1920, 1080);
                glVertex2f(0, 1080);
            glEnd();

            //example light, a rectangle trough which i should see the scene
            glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2f(100, 100);
                glVertex2f(300, 100);
                glVertex2f(300, 300);
                glVertex2f(100, 300);
            glEnd();

            //Deactivate the framebuffer object
            glPopAttrib();
            glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

            glUseProgram(shaderProgram3);//this is the shader program
            //Render the framebuffer object to the screen

            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_frameBufferTexture);
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
                    glVertex2f(0, 0);
                    glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
                    glVertex2f(1920, 0); 
                    glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
                    glVertex2f(1920, 1080);
                    glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
                    glVertex2f(0, 1080);
                glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glUseProgram(0);

    Display.update();
    Display.sync(60);
```

This is the shader

```
uniform sampler2D backbuffer;

void main( void ) {    
    vec2 position;
    position.x = gl_FragCoord.x/1920;
    position.y = gl_FragCoord.y/1080;
    vec4 color = texture2D(backbuffer, position);
    gl_FragColor.x -=1-color.x;
    gl_FragColor.y -=1-color.y;
    gl_FragColor.z -=1-color.z;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the following in your shader :

```
gl_FragColor.x -=1-color.x;
gl_FragColor.y -=1-color.y;
gl_FragColor.z -=1-color.z;
```

You are assuming that when you enter `main()` `gl_FragColor` contains the current pixel color of the current framebuffer.

But this is not the case ! `gl_FragColor` is a color you need to set in the shader and until you set it, its value will be undefined (in your case it seems to be set to black), it will never contain the "current framebuffer color" (check the specs, this applies to all versions of OpenGL / OpenGLES there are no exceptions to this).

To get the current framebuffer color you need to use OpenGL extensions like [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) for mobile GPUs and sadly this kind of extension does not exist for desktop GPUs (but you can use [Image Load Store](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) with OpenGL4).

But here I digress as I do not think you need any of those extensions, what you need instead is simply to enable [blending](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) when rendering your mask and configure the blending formulaes correctly to achieve your effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but atleast can i access the texture current pixels, because for multiple lights they should blend.

Comment: I do not understand what you call "texture" ? Are you talking about your scene pixels or the light mask pixels or something else ? Also before thinking about multiple lights let's first make this work for one light ...

Comment: If you want to have multiple lights in your "light framebuffer" then this is the same process : at each frame, you clear the frame buffer with black, then draw light1 inside, then you enable opengl blending and draw light2 inside, then light3 ... At the end you have a framebuffer with all lights inside which you draw over your scene, again using opengl blending.

Comment: Thanks again and one last question. I now draw it but I am having a hard time thinking of a blend func parameters so that when the light mask is fully white, it should render the scene color and when the light mask is fully black, it should render the light mask.

Comment: Edit i did it with glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR,GL_ZERO);

Comment: `gl_FragColor` is not guaranteed to be initialized to black. If you don't set it, the value is undefined.

Comment: @Reto: you are totally right, I edit the answer to reflect this